# My B string on my bass keeps hitting the pickup

Tags: recording, bass-guitar, pick-ups, action, 5-string-bass-guitar

I went to record bass for my band a while ago and in some fills or moments I use the B string on my 5 string Sire Bass. Sometimes though, the Low B accidentally hits the pickup which makes a loud click noise.
I've managed to finish the EP, but without the trouble of me sometimes accidentally hitting the Low B against the pickups. I really like playing hard and enthusiastically, so sometimes playing the Low B is a no go.
Also, my Low B feels a tad bit floppier compared to the rest. I don't have much trouble with playing it, the only problem I have is it hitting my pickup and it making a loud click noise

Anyone else having this Issue? Or better yet, anyone who got rid of this?
What do you recommend? Bigger gauge B string? Higher action? Different play style? Different pickups?

Comment: Is it a Squier bass? What thickness are the strings?

Comment: If, for example, you only use the B string for a low D, you could simply tune it up to that D note, and play it open. Being tighter may solve the problem. If, like me, you use it as an extra string when playing higher up the fretboard, then a thicker string will be the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Can you adjust the pickup height?

That would be my first adjustment, assuming the rest feels right while you're playing it. Any other adjustment would change how it plays.

Dropping the pickup back would make it cleaner-sounding & a tad quieter, but wouldn't change what it's like to actually play.

Comment: That would be my first move too, +1. One thing Hugo, check the string balance, you might need to lower both sides of the pickup(s) to keep the volume between strings even. A thicker B string wouldn’t hurt either.

Comment: And possibly raising the B string saddle at the same time, if the above is insufficient.